# DNN 6.2 Installing module development environment

Tags: asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke

I have installed DNN 6.2 and am able to access the portal from the basic install. I am working with IIS 5.1, SQL Server 2008 and VS 2010 - But I have become confused on how I am supposed to create a new web project in VS.  It says to use the dotnetnuke templates but I cannot find them.  Anyone have any pointers?  I will be migrating a VB.NET web site into DNN and as I am completely new to this - am a little lost. Thank you for your input.

SD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at my DNN development tutorials, start at the bottom and read up

http://www.christoc.com/tutorials

You'll want an older release of my templates at

https://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/

The latest templates are all for Visual Studio 2012/2013